# Is 2.5% (12.5k page views per day) good as compared to my total index pages which is 5,00,000 pages?

Tags: web-development, search-engine-indexing, page

Is 2.5% (12.5k page views per day)  good as compared to my total index pages which is 5,00,000 pages?

If not, how much % should be a good one?

Answer (score 1):

**There is NO right or wrong answer.** It is impossible to *even guess* without an idea on what your pages are about.

Think about it. Imagine if you have a news site with 5M articles, you probably have very few articles read each day since people reach much more about recent events. Then you are a store with 5M articles for sale and people only buy 2% of what you sell. You'd be out of business quickly!